# Optimizing Database for 1M+ Post WordPress site

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, performance, optimization

I'm a designer turned novice developer and don't know too much about database optimization. I recently landed a client who runs a content database with just over 1M pages.

I'm re-designing their site, and against my recommendation they are wanting to switch over to WordPress. They've already got a script to mass post their pages via an API but part of my requirements will be making sure the site runs smoothly.

In my limited knowledge I probably want to:

- Remove any 'sort by date' or 'sort by views' that would be database intensive.
- Disable any full-text search.
- (Possibly disable search all together as most of their traffic is from search engine referrals and not the main page).

But, even with those I imagine this database is going to get pretty clunky, and take up a lot of room.

1. What are best practices to working with a massive database
   (especially in WordPress)?
2. Are there things I should be doing before they start importing posts
   to make sure the database is optimized?
3. Are there some general maintenance practices that go along with
   databases of this size?
4. Are there any functions in WordPress (other than sort by date/sort
   by views) that I should remove/disable to avoid a hungup database?

Sidenote: Yes, I know WordPress is probably not well designed for this type of site - that choice is out of my control. Yes, I know I am in over my head.

Comment: Sorting a million things isn’t really slow when you have database indexes. How big is the average page? What does it represent?

Comment: Enabling/disabling full text search is something of a moot point if none of the tables are using full text search (are they using FTS?).  Having a table with a million records in it is not as bad as you think, provided that you have indices to help you with queries which might need them to perform well.

Comment: Ryan - The posts are each around 1000 words of recipe instructions. No images.

Tim - No FTS, I'm not really familiar with indices, do you know of a good beginner resource?

Comment: `wp_postmeta` is inefficiently designed; [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) is a speedup.

Comment: Long time ago now, but see if this plugin helps. https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/